# How to set 'INSERT IGNORE' in db_insert without db_merge

Tags: database

Is anyone know how to set 'INSERT IGNORE' in db_insert?

I cannot use db_merge because I'm going to insert many rows.

```
$query = db_insert('table')->fields(array('foo', 'bar'));
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $query->values(array(
    'foo' => $row->foo,
    'bar' => $row->bar,
  ));
}
$query->execute();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got two options:

1. Subclass [`InsertQuery`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!query.inc/class/InsertQuery/7) and add that functionality in yourself (it's currently not implemented)
2. Use `db_query()` to run a raw SQL string instead.

The only mention of `INSERT IGNORE` in the Drupal 7 codebase is in [`DatabaseConnection_mysql:nextId`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21mysql%21database.inc/function/DatabaseConnection_mysql%3A%3AnextId/7); it's not actually used, but in its place is a raw query string containing `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, that gets passed directly to `db_query()`.

I may be wrong, but I'd assume that's as good an indication as any that a raw SQL string along with `db_query()` is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Although it's not possible to use "INSERT IGNORE", there is a way you can get around this in PHP. Something like this:

```
try {
    $insertID = db_insert('crawl_data')->fields(array(
        'url' => $url, 
    ))->execute();
} catch (Exception $ex) {

}
```

In this example I have a database of "urls". But i dont want to first do a check if the item is in the database. I want it to happen in one go. So this is sort of the same behaviour as "insert ignore".

However, it's generally bad to have this:

```
catch (Exception $ex) {
    // open space
}
```

So it might be better to do this:

```
catch (Exception $ex) {
    $error = $ex->getMessage();
    if (strpos($error, 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation') !== false) {
        // then we know it's an error we can ignore
    }
    else {
        // just throw the error again
        throw $e;
    } 
}
```

It's either this or doing two database queries.